# i have enabled the Uart in linux source and created a image how to test the uart working

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, uart

hi I am newbie please help me
i have enabled the Uart in linux source and created a image,and while kernel boot time its showing me the log

```
Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 5 ports, IRQ sharing disabled                        
serial8250.0: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x4000c000 (irq = 5) is a 16550A                    
console [ttyS0] enabled                                                         
serial8250.2: ttyS1 at MMIO 0x40098000 (irq = 7) is a 16550A                    
serial8250.3: ttyS2 at MMIO 0x4009c000 (irq = 8) is a 16550A
```

and ttyS0 is used for interaction between host terminal and my target board
that is working well, I want to test ttyS1(connection tx=P0.10 rx=P0.11) and ttyS2(connection tx=P0.1 rx=P0.3) and use those for the other device. before using those for other device to coonect I want to test those by shorting tx and rx 
how to test the these uart working

Comment: and my target board is LPC1788

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of terminal emulators that will work with serial ports, including microcom, minicom, nanocom, picocom, etc.  See if any of these were installed along with your Linux distribution.  When you have RX tied to TX and open one of these emulators then any keys you type should appear on the screen.

Additionally there is a very simple POSIX communications test application out on the web.  Here's a link to one of the places you can get it: http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/programming/c/linux_pgcserial.html

Comment: I am using uclinux with my board its not having microcom or minicom ect is there any other way to do this..??

Comment: thanks I used busy box microcom in my target and got the out put

Comment: Glad you got it to work.  I added one more method for anybody else who happens across your question.  If this helped you it would be nice if you marked it as the answer.

Comment: hi that works fine now I want to read/write using serial communication ttyS1 ow can I do it.

Comment: that means I want reader rfid reader output serial using ttyS1 and display read data back in the terminal. how to do please guide me.

Comment: i have tried like this but no result
 n = open("/dev/ttyS1", O_RDWR);
    if (n == -1)
     {
     printf("Error: %s \n",strerror(errno));
     }
     else
     {
     printf("...uart2 opening\n");
     }
     written = write(n,&stdin,12);
     nread = read(written,&luc_Serial_Data, 12);

Comment: Did you look at the link that I added to my answer?  You will have to modify it to open /dev/ttyS1, but it shows the basics of talking to the serial port with C.

Comment: yeah I have gone through that but no help from that.
please suggest me if any other way

Comment: Putting code in comments is not very helpful.  You need to either edit your question or open a new one and reference this question.