# How to use a serial port to communicate with an RFID reader

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, uart

I am beginner, 
I have enabled the uart2 by using the make menuconfig in my linux source. I am using LPC1788 cortex m3, in that uart tx is connected to P0.10 and rx to P0.11,
I want to utilize the uart to read the RFID card using SL031 (http://www.stronglink-rfid.com/download/SL031-User-Manual.pdf) reader, which will be connected to rx and tx pins that means P0.10 and P0.11. please guide me how to read the RFID and save the the data received.
by enabling the the uart I have tested the uart working by shorting tx and rx,now i want to connect the reader to those tx and rx and read the data. how can i do this.

Comment: Hi Amar,
What linux distro are you running on the system?
What application(program) did you use to confirm that UART is working, during the loopback(short) test? Cant you use the same application to communicate with SL031?

Comment: @amar as I have stated in your previous post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162659/i-have-enabled-the-uart-in-linux-source-and-created-a-image-how-to-test-the-uart/17162988?noredirect=1#comment24887338_17162988) you really need to provide us with the code that you have tried already.  Please provide it in the question and not in a comment.  I do want to help you out on this one.

Comment: @microMolvi , I am using uclinux(kernel version-2.6.33).I have used busy box microcom to confirm that the uart loob back is working fine.and I dont kwou that the same application can be used for SSL031 regarding that i am seeking a the help.how can I go head provide me some hint so that i can go forward to connect and achieve my work

Answer (score 0):

**Task:** Write/send data & read/receive data over UART to/from SL031 using microcom.

**Problem:** Your device expects data/commands in hexadecimal format and, as far as I know, microcom does not directly support sending data in hexadecimal format.

**Solution:**

**To write/send:**
Use a hex editor, [Bless Hex Editor](http://home.gna.org/bless/) for instance, to write a series of commands you want to send to SL031. Redirect/pipeline this data, using basic shell commands, to microcom.

**To read/receive:**
Capture the data of microcom in a file and analyze it with a hex editor. You can do this by redirecting/pipelining the output of microcom to a log file.

Hope this helps. If it does kindly accept the answer :)
Ask me if you need further clarification.

Comment: @amar  It appears that you have asked 15 questions and yet to accept any of the answers as acceptable.  Please consider selecting acceptable answers.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, creating a configuration file did the work. After installing pcscd and pcsc-tools I created a file:

sudo vi /etc/reader.conf.d/reader.conf

```
FRIENDLYNAME      "AKAM serial"
DEVICENAME        /dev/ttyUSB0
LIBPATH           /usr/lib/pcsc/drivers/serial/libccidtwin.so
CHANNELID         1
```